# how do you select the image you want to use when posting a link via facebook php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

how do you select the image you want to use when posting a link via facebook php sdk

this is the code  i have:

```
$facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", array(
message => "TESTING FACEBOOK API",
link => "http://www.penpalparade.com"
));
```

Is it possible to chose the picture which is displayed with the link as i dont want it to be the first one, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options.

1. In the HTML output from the link's URL, have the og tag specified for og:image correctly. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
2. On feed's post you can specify "picture" with the URL for the image. (See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)